# How to use SAPI's SetNotifyCallbackFunction() in a CLR project with Windows Form as the interface window?

Tags: c++, dll, callback, sapi, speech

I'm trying to write a dll plugin for Winamp. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and Microsoft SAPI 5.1. I created the interface window using Windows Form (System::Windows::Forms::Form).

I tried to use SetNotifyWIndowMessage(), but the method is never called when I speak to the microphone. So I tried using SetNotifyCallbackFunction(), but I got a compile error saying that I should use '&' in front of the method name in the parameter. However, when I add the '&', I got another compile error saying that i can't take the address of the method unless creating delegate instance.

What should I do? Someone please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as indicated, you need to create a delegate instance to wrap your callback.  But don't go there, SAPI 5.1 is quite outdated.  Updates are no longer shipped because the .NET framework has a *very* nice wrapper for it.  Check out the System.Speech.Recognition namespace and the SpeechRecognitionEngine class.  You'll want to use the SpeechRegonized event.  You'll find plenty of code samples in the [MSDN Library pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) for the class.

Comment: It seems that I can't create a delegate instance due to the Windows Form class, I don't know how to do that. Is using the .net framework easy? cause i need to submit this project next friday. do you think i still have time to change? however, i will not have time to come back if it fails.

Comment: The odds to get this done on Friday with System.Speech are much better.  You didn't really get started if you didn't get notifications going yet.

Comment: Hi, I've modified the code to suit my environment, but I'm still having errors I can't solve.

1. sre->SpeechRecognized += gcnew EventHandler (&Dialog::sre_SpeechRecognized);

generates compile error C3352: 'void gen_myplugin::Dialog::sre_SpeechRecognized(System::Object ^,System::Speech::Recognition::SpeechRecognizedEventArgs ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)'

2. each cases inside switch (e->Result->Text) generates compile error C2051: case expression not constant

How do I solve them?

Comment: gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^> (this, &Dialog::sre_SpeechRecognized).  
You can't use a string in a switch statement, use if() statements.  Please start a new thread if you have any more questions.

Comment: Please answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623826/net-speech-recognition-plugin-runtime-error-unhandled-exception-what-could-pos